# Slick2D Mouse Click not working in Windows 10

Tags: java, windows-10, lwjgl, slick2d

I created a simple mouse listener example using Slick2D in Windows 10 environment in Intellij. It is not reporting the correct coordinates or not working at all:

State class:

```
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;
public class StateMain extends BasicGameState
{
@Override
public int getID() {return 0;}
@Override
public void init(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game) throws SlickException {}
@Override
public void render(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, Graphics g) throws SlickException {}
@Override
public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame game, int delta) throws SlickException
    {
    System.out.printf("Position: %d,%d\n", Mouse.getX(), Mouse.getY()); // Only reports position (-1,-1)
    }
@Override
public void mouseClicked(int button, int x, int y, int clickCount)
    {
    System.out.printf("Clicked: %d,%d\n", x, y); // Doesn't report
    }
@Override
public void mousePressed(int button, int x, int y)
    {
    System.out.printf("Pressed: %d,%d\n", x, y); // Only reports (-1,501)
    }
}
```

I have the following files in my libs folder:

jinput-dx8.dll
jinput-dx8_64.dll
jinput-raw.dll
jinput-raw_64.dll
lwjgl.dll
lwjgl64.dll
OpenAL32.dll
OpenAL64.dll

The following are my VM arguments:

-Djava.library.path=libs/ -Dorg.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL=true

I always get the following error when running the code:

Oct 05, 2017 11:26:30 AM net.java.games.input.DefaultControllerEnvironment getControllers
WARNING: Found unknown Windows version: Windows 10
Oct 05, 2017 11:26:30 AM net.java.games.input.DefaultControllerEnvironment getControllers
INFO: Attempting to use default windows plug-in.
Oct 05, 2017 11:26:30 AM net.java.games.input.DefaultControllerEnvironment getControllers
INFO: Loading: net.java.games.input.DirectAndRawInputEnvironmentPlugin

I suspect that the input environment plugin it is loading is causing the weird mouse position errors?

Comment: Which lwjgl version are you using? I'm also encountering these warnings, but they are not breaking anything.

Comment: I'm using lwjgl 2.9.3. Is your mouse listener working?

Comment: Yeah its all working for me.

Could you try lwjgl 2.9.1 and put this in your init method: System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.input.Mouse.allowNegativeMouseCoords", "false");

Comment: Yep 2.9.1 works! Even without the statement, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working for me. Could you try lwjgl 2.9.1 and put this in your init method: System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.input.Mouse.allowNegativeMouse‌​Coords", "false");